# Flutter how to keep the keyboard showing / active when user taps outside

Tags: flutter, textfield

The solution is probably simple but I don't find the answer after hours spending searching...

I have a textfield and when tapping on it a keyboard appears : just normal, that's what I want !
But I want the keyboard to stay on screen (and to stay active) until the user hit the Done button (to start the onSubmitted method). 
Why am I asking this?
The user has to enter a city into the textfield and once it is done the onSubmitted method asks the Geocoder to do his work. I want to avoid the following :

- That the user taps outside the keyboard once he has finished to input the city
  and because the Done button was not hit the onSubmitted method is not
  performed (and Geocoder not called)
- Calling the Geocoder in the onChanged method what would cause
  errors

  ```
              child: new TextField(
                controller: textFieldVilleController,
                onChanged: (String string) {
                  setState(() {
                    villeChoisie = string;
                  });

                },
                onSubmitted: (String string) {
                  setState(() {
                    villeChoisie = string;
                  });
                  coordFromVilleChoisie();
                },
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    fontFamily: 'CopperplateBold',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate("Ville"),
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                      BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple, width: 2.0)),
                ),
              ),
  ```

I tried the onEditingComplete method but it doesn't work.

I would be very grateful if you could help me on this !

Thanks a lot,

Bernard

Comment: If you are taking the textField value at Done button , You can probably use ```var textController = TextEditingController();``` and then ```onPressed()``` of Done Button you can get the value as ```textController.text```

Comment: Keyboard still shows even if you press outside area, must be wrong somewhere,  post most of the code.

Comment: Sorry, I have a formatting problem to import more code...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

`SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');` for hiding

and `SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show');` for showing keyboard

`import 'package:flutter/services.dart';` is required

Comment: Thanks but the problem is not showing the keyboard but keeping it on screen / active when the user taps outside.

Comment: What? I'm not :D